# android:AsyncTask for background operations

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am playing with SQLite and SQL server databases to sync each other. I enclosed separate table updation in separate methods.  it can execute successfully from the main thread but it takes long time. how can i enclose those methods in asynctask ?

say I have 4 methods, for my four tables which syncs data between server and sqlite.... when i am running all these methods under main UI thread it takes time to complete those operations. So my question is how o import those methods into doInBacckground of async task.

Comment: what about posting your code ?

Comment: i cant post my code because of some issues....

Comment: without code cant give better solution